# How do programs use other programs that are not in the same programming language

Tags: programming-languages

How do programs use other programs that aren't in the same language?
For example, Windows is in C++ but the kernel is in C.
I've also seen Java programs use C programs as well.

How do they do this?

Do they use master classes? Like `class Whatever : MasterClassName`?

Comment: Windows is not written in C++, it's written in C. Therefore, there are no classes involved. Windows uses interfaces instead, when it needs cross-language compatible objects. Java programs use C dynamic link libraries (DLLs) for the most part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you've seen a Java program use a C program. Do you mean a Java program use an executable that was generated from C code?

On a slightly different note, two programs can communicate with each other through, among other things, a DLL, a socket interface (TCP/UDP), a file, a database, and/or CORBA.

Answer (score 0):

The programming language is not what is relevant for communication between programs. Programming languages are just a means of making programs readable for humans; what the computer actually executes is machine code.

In order to communicate, programs need to make several assumptions about how this communication looks like. This mechanism is generally called a protocol.

For example, applications communicate with an OS kernel typically via a syscall protocol. They store some special values in the processor registers, and use a machine code instruction to switch into kernel mode. The kernel then examines the aforementioned special values to decide which operation needs to be executed (e.g. open file, print on terminal, etc.). The meaning of specific values is specified by the protocol.

DLLs, files, databases, IPC, networking etc. all are communication protocols, in this particular interpretation. They are usually implemented in terms of more low-level protocols, such as kernel syscalls, though.